# how to make changes to unspecified position strings?

Tags: python, string

I want to delete the vowels from my string and add '.' before other letters.

my code

```py
x = input()
y = x.lower()

for h in y :
    if h == 'a' or  h == 'e' or h == 'i' or h == 'u' or h == 'o' :
        new = y.replace('a' ,'')
        new1 = new.replace('i','')
        new2 = new1.replace('o','')
        new3 = new2.replace('e','')
        new4 = new3.replace('u','')
        new5 = '.'.join (new4)
        new6 = '.' + new5[0:]
        print(new6)
    else:
        z = '.'.join(y)
        r = '.' + z[0:]
        print(r)
```

run the program

```
hello
.h.e.l.l.o
.h.l.l
.h.e.l.l.o
.h.e.l.l.o
.h.l.l
```

I want `'.h.l.l'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing multiple statements printed is because you're calling `print` in every iteration of the loop.

However, the bigger problem is that you're not holding onto the results of the individual iterations.

Here's what your loop should look like:

```
new_word=y
for h in y:
    if h in ('a','e','i','o','u'):
        new_word=new_word.replace(h,'')
    else:
        new_word=new_word.replace(h,'.'+h)
```

However, there's a much cleaner way of accomplishing what you want.

```
new_word=[c for c in y if c not in ('a','e','i','o','u')] # remove all vowels and convert to a list
new_word='.'.join(new_word) # since we only have consonants left, put periods in between them
if new_word: # if the word isn't empty, then we need a period before its first letter
    new_word='.'+new_word
```

Or, in one line:

```
new_word=''.join('.'+c for c in y if c not in ('a','e','i','o','u'))
```